# Find files whos filenames match pattern in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am using Linux version of emacs and I would like to use its grep (or rgrep) function to list all filenames matching a pattern, and ideally this should be recursive. I want to be able to call this from the eshell. I'm an emacs newb so if there are more convenient ways of doing this please list those as well, thanks!

EDIT: The purpose in this case is to ensure there are no binary executables in the file list, I don't need the output to go anywhere.

Comment: `grep` is for searching the file contents. I think you want `find` instead.
How do you want to use this list of files, once you obtain it?
The way you use it determines the method of obtaining.

Comment: See this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/how-to-find-binary-executables-within-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-name-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd> is what you want.

Comment: What should the format of the filename wildcard be? It looks like it takes shell style wildcard characters rather than regex. Is there an option to use regexp?

Comment: As the function docstring says, by default the command becomes `find . -name 'PATTERN' -ls`, so that dictates the syntax of PATTERN. In fact the variable `find-name-arg` is used, and may be either `-name` or `-iname`. If you want to use different find arguments, `find-name-dired` serves as a useful template to create your own function.

Comment: I should have pointed out explicitly in my previous comment that using `-regex` or `-iregex` as the argument would likely give you the behaviour you want. GNU find uses emacs regex syntax by default (see the `-regextype` argument).

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `M-x grep-find` and then tweak the `find` command with the `-executable` flag to suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

There's one more way (as is common) to do this using Dired. Suppose you have the directory you want to search in now visible in Dired buffer. Move the point to it and do <kbd>C-u i</kbd>`R`<kbd>RET</kbd> - this will expand all subdirectories recursively in the same buffer. Now <kbd>* *</kbd> will select all executable files in all subdirectories.

If you then want to hide the rest, do <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>.

PS. For your purpose, Dired will report in the minibuffer how many executable files it found, so you'd not need to do the second step. Second step is for the case if you wanted to further work with the files.